# UISheetPresentationController with a tabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I would like to permanently display a UISheetPresentationController for a UIViewController, while still showing the tabBar. Is this possible? Currently, the UISheetPresentationController is presented, but it covers up the tabBar like a normal modal presentation.

Comment: can you share any image of what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I really don't know how to share an image because I cannot produce what I want.

Comment: Something like presenting the sheet this way
`tabBarController?.presentViewController(xxx)`
and 
`tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false`

Comment: No, that does not work

Comment: I saw this about related to the question you asked. I too am looking for a solution. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708728